# Accessing a struct given an unknown pointer to a memory address - C

Tags: c, memory

Suppose I am given a (void*) ptr (my basic understanding is, it represents a pointer to a region of unknown data type) passed through the parameter of a function. I am trying to figure out how to access and check if a struct exists a few addresses behind.

To clarify, I am working with a big char array (not malloced) and the ptr passed into the function should point to an address of an unspecified data type within the array. Located before this data is a struct for which I am trying to access.

```
void function(void *ptr)
{
       void *structPtr = (void*)((void*)ptr - sizeof(struct block));
}
```

Would this work to get me a pointer to the address of the struct located behind the initial "ptr"? And if so, how could I check if it is the block struct?

Apologizes in advance, I know this code is not specific as I am fairly new to the concepts entirely but also, I am in the process of coming up with an algorithm and not yet implementing it. Any references to possibly useful information are much appreciated.

Comment: You must like "tap dancing on land-mines...". In the code above there is no guarantee the address `ptr - sizeof(struct block)` is something you can access. There is nothing wrong with the arithmetic (a cast to `char*` will cure your `void*` problem), but that is not a reliable way to look backwards in memory (to a lower address). We will need more to comment further. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1) You aren't allowed to do math with `void` pointers (technically speaking, although some compilers (gcc) allow it). 2) `structPtr` needs a type other than `void *`, or it's rather useless. 3) There's no way to know for sure that what you're pointing to is actually a `struct block`, but signatures and CRCs are the common methods for giving some level of confidence.

Comment: This is an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please explain what you want to achieve by finding out wether there is anything before the referenced memory. Assume that it is impossible and describe what you really need instead of the imposible. Then people here will more likely be able to tell you how to achieve your actual possible goal than they can help you with doing the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is risky as you must be sure that you address a correct place in memory. Usually, we add some magic number in struct block so that we can test here that we are not going anywhere.

This pattern is generally used in memory allocators, 
have a look to https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of writing this is something like:

```
...function(void *ptr) {
    struct block *hdr = (struct block *)ptr - 1;
```

relying on pointer arithmetic automatically scaling by the size of the pointed at type.  As long as all the pointers passed in here were originally created by taking a pointer to a valid `struct block` and adding 1 to it (to get the memory after it), you should be fine.